# Catch fancybox error and try another type

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I want to catch a fancybox error (The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later.) and try another fancybox type.

Like this. First time It tries ajax and if that returns error, try iframe.

```
    jQuery('.lightwindow').click(function() {
        var element = this;
        jQuery(element).fancybox({
            error: function() {

                // If this didn't work, try iframe
                jQuery(element).fancybox({
                    type: 'iframe',
                    autoSize: true
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

But that doesn't work. It will just show the error from the first fancybox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `error` does not exists, you can set the `type` to `'ajax'` and edit the ajax settings like this `ajax : { error : function(){ ...change fancybox and load... } }` then you have:

```
jQuery(element).fancybox({
    type : 'ajax',
    ajax : {
        error: function() {
            // If this didn't work, try iframe
            jQuery(element).fancybox({
                type: 'iframe',
                autoSize: true
            });
        }
    }
 });
```

But it is probably better to check before the request is made whether to use ajax or an iframe